# Display which widget has focus

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

Before you read:
I am a complete novice at programming let alone Python. I don't expect solutions. I will appreciate it even if I just get a pointer in the right direction. If you feel the way I've requested help is unrefined, please let me know so next time I need help, I'll do a better job at asking.

Goal:
I'm making a program to test how to get a program to respond depending on which widget has to focus on. Currently, I'm just having it respond by displaying 'what' has focus.
Eventually, once I've figured this out I can implement what I've learnt into another program I'm working on was focusing on an entry field will result in the field clearing of all input. So naturally, I will want this program to not only change the label but the entry widget too. That will be for later.

Progress:
I've managed to have the program print which widget has a focus in both the terminal and in a label widget.

Problem:
My issue is that the message is ugly, and I want it to look neater.

Example of the problem:
Instead of saying "Entry has focus", it says ".!frame.!entry {has focus}"

I have tried:
Checking if other's have made similar programs. The only one I found was how I made this much progress but it didn't make the text nicer. I've also done research on various sites on how Python handles certain commands I've used in this program.
I am a novice with programming so I admit I'm not completely sure what the best way to run this program is and so trying to research it is difficult for me.

Code:

```
# Call tkinter tools
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

"""
TODO:
Add different widgets that can 'gain' focus.
Print in the terminal which widget has focus.
Change entry and label text depending on which widget has focus.
"""

# Develop the window and frame
root = Tk()
root.title("Focus Test")
root.columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)

frame = ttk.Frame(root, padding = "1 1 1 1")
frame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = (N, S, E, W))

# Resizes columns in frame
for col in range(1, 3):
    frame.columnconfigure(col, weight = 1)

# Resizes rows in frame
for row in range(1, 3):
    frame.rowconfigure(row, weight = 1)

# Add response label
foc_labvar = StringVar()
foc_labvar.set("No focus")
foc_lab = ttk.Label(frame, width = 7, textvariable = foc_labvar)
foc_lab.grid(column = 2, row = 2, sticky = (W, E))

# Add entry box
foc_entvar = StringVar()
foc_entvar.set("Entry widget")
foc_ent = ttk.Entry(frame, width = 7, textvariable = foc_entvar)
foc_ent.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = (W, E))

# Add button
foc_butvar = StringVar()
foc_butvar.set("Button widget")
foc_but = ttk.Button(frame, width = 7, textvariable = foc_butvar)
foc_but.grid(column = 2, row = 1, sticky = (W, E))

# Focus commands
def focus(event):
    focused_widget = frame.focus_get()
    foc_labvar.set((focused_widget, "has focus"))
    print(focused_widget, "has focus")

# Bind mouse click to run focus command
root.bind("<Button-1>", focus)

# Resize widgets inside frame
for child in frame.winfo_children():
    child.grid_configure(padx = 5, pady = 5)


root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just easily do this having `event` handle the widget identification part, like:

```
def focus(event):
    focused_widget = event.widget.winfo_class()
    foc_labvar.set((focused_widget, "has focus")) # Or f'{focused_widget} has focus'
    print(focused_widget, "has focus")
```

Here `event` will provide the widget with `widget` method and then you can use any widget methods on it, like `focus()` or `insert()`(if its an entry widget) and so on. Here `winfo_class` should work, because it is a universal method and works with all the widgets.

More info on `winfo_class`, it will provide the class of the widget, like `TButton` for buttons, because that is how `tk` refers to them. If you adamantly still want to get rid of the `T` then just go for `event.widget.winfo_class()[1:]` to trim the 'T' off.

Comment: @NatusPotatus That is because of the way you are using a tuple of inside of `set`, instead use `foc_labvar.set(f'{focused_widget} has focus')` or `foc_labvar.set(focused_widget+' has focus')`

Comment: I apologise for removing my previous comment. I hadn't properly interpreted what you said, and I realised it, so I wanted to give it an honest go at understanding. However, you've given more input now and so I'd like to take some more time to try everything you've suggested before I leave a proper response out of respect for your time. I will update you later with how I went with your advice. Thank you.

Comment: Okay so I've had a look and tried this. This is the most concise solution provided and includes everything and a little more. I'm not completely understanding why the `f` and `{}` brackets make such a change. I do understand why using `+` works because `.set` can't handle too many arguments so concatenating them is treated as 1 argument (I think).

Comment: @NatusPotatus If you are asking about why '{}' came in the answer, then it is because of the way tcl deals with reading lists/tuples. So we dont give them lists or tuples, instead a string. Take a read [here](https://realpython.com/python-string-formatting/) more about `f` strings

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll do some further research into these `f` strings. Also, more about tcl. I really appreciate your help here. This will be my last response as to not add too much clutter for those just looking for an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an `if` statement like this:

```py
def focus(event):
    focused_widget = frame.focus_get() # You can also use `event.widget` like what @CoolCloud did.
    if focused_widget == foc_ent:
        foc_labvar.set("Entry has focus")
    if focused_widget == foc_but:
        foc_labvar.set("Button has focus")
```

Comment: This worked!
So simple. I like your way of thinking for this problem. I didn't even think to just add some `if` statements. Everything I was researching was overly complicated which is a problem I've been facing with my own personal self. I need to remember to dial it back a bit and think if there's a simpler way of looking at the problem. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Well using `event.widget` instead of `frame.focus_get()` would have been better like what @CoolCloud used in his/her answer.

Comment: But you've given a good example of how you can do it either way. Everyone who has posted has contributed to me getting better. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can give widgets a name of your choosing. You can then use `winfo_name` to get the name of the widget. About the only required for a name is that it cannot have a period in it.

Also, you should bind to `<FocusIn>` and `<FocusOut>` so that your code works even if the focus changes via the keyboard.

```
foc_ent = ttk.Entry(..., name="foc entry")
foc_but = ttk.Button(..., name="foc button")
...
def focus(event):
    focused_widget = frame.focus_get()
    if focused_widget:
        foc_labvar.set(f"{focused_widget.winfo_name()} as focus")
    else:
        foc_labvar.set("nothing has focus")

root.bind("<FocusIn>", focus)
root.bind("<FocusOut>", focus)
```

Comment: I did not know I could assign names to widgets. This is great stuff. Extremely helpful. The code itself doesn't give exactly the desired outcome but you've given me something to work with here. Also, thank you for mentioning how `<FocusIn/Out>` works to include changing focus with the keyboard, this was a feature I didn't know I wanted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the advice provided. Here is what I've ended up with which is working the way I had imagined in my head plus a little extra from everyone's help:

```
# Focus commands
def focus(event):
    focused_widget = event.widget.winfo_class()[1:]
    foc_labvar.set(focused_widget + " has focus")
    foc_entvar.set(focused_widget + " has focus")
    print(focused_widget, "has focus")

# Bind mouse and keyboard to run focus command
root.bind("<Button-1>", focus)
root.bind("<FocusIn>", focus)
root.bind("<FocusOut>", focus)
```

Comment: You don't need to bind to `<Button-1>` since you're already binding to `<FocusIn>` and `<FocusOut>`. When you click, that sets the focus to the widget and thus the other bindings will do the job whether you click or use the keyboard or you call a function that sets the focus.

Comment: You're right. The program works well without `<Button-1>`. I will keep it in, though, because without it, it seems that it doesn't tell you when frame or label have focus. Might not be required, but I like that it does it. Thank you for pointing that out, very useful for future programs.